# QTP script works in big screen but not in small screen

Tags: testing, vbscript, automation, automated-tests, qtp

I am using QTP 11.0 and a java button in my application is highlighted in big monitor screen(19 or 20 inch) but not in Laptop screen(14 or 15 inch).
I have to click the button and a pop up will be seen,this works fine in big screen but in laptop screen the pop up does not appear.Is there any workaround?

In small screen the scroll bar appears and the java button is below the screen, but in big screen its appeared without scrolling so its working fine with the big screen.
Also i have tried if scroll down is possible through scripting in small screen ,but scroll down does not work NOR does pgDown pgUP works in the application.

Addins selected are ActiveX,Java,Web

Advanced thanks...

Answer (score 0):

As per the given information I assume that the problem is with the object properties of the java button. Could you try adding only htmlid/name property & try highlighting the object in both the screens? Please disable object identification, location & indexing if applicable. If possible share the properties of the object for further analysis.

Comment: I newly add the object to the repository and try to highlight it.No error message is seen,but the button is NOT highlighted as well.

Comment: I newly add the object to OR which has index used in it.In case I remove the index and add some visual relation which is the simple label name of the field adjacent to it,in big monitor it recognises,but not in laptop screen due to different resolutions.

Note :The visual relation field is added in the OR which is recognised without any index or visual relation

Answer (score 0):

Does QTP fail to recognise the button during play back? QTP may not highlight the button because it is not visible; but in most cases it will be able to perform actions (such as click event) on the button. Make the button visible in web page / application and try clicking on Highlight button in QTP.